How to recreate browser zoom in javascript?
Since there seems to be no way to directly set browsers' zoom level via js, I thought to override the browser zoom and code my own.
This code works correctly when starting from scale = 1, but I'm having trouble with the scenario where I'm already zoomed a little and move my cursor to another part of the image to zoom further. Doing so, the focus of the zoom always jumps further than it's supposed to, because changing the transform-origin causes the whole image to shift.  Maybe setting the transform-origin is not the right approach...


var myDiv = document.querySelector(".container");
var img = myDiv.querySelector("img");

var scale = 1.0;

myDiv.addEventListener('wheel', function (ev) {
  if(!ev.ctrlKey)
  {
    return;
  }
  ev.preventDefault();
  const rect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  img.style.transformOrigin = x + "px " + y + "px"
  
  scale += event.deltaY * -0.005;

  // Apply scale transform
  img.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
})
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/600/200">
</div>




You can take advantage of transform: scale(1.5)


var myDiv = document.querySelector(".container");
var img = myDiv.querySelector("img");

var scale = 1.0

myDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
  const rect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  img.style.transformOrigin = x + "px " + y + "px"

})

myDiv.addEventListener('wheel', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  scale += event.deltaY * -0.001;

  // Apply scale transform
  img.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
})
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/600/200">
</div>




Thanks for this. It doesn't solve my problem, but it helped me to see the cause of the problem- changing the transform origin causes the image to shift. I've copied and modified it in my original post. Since I've removed the mousemove listener, the motion that normally happens there now happens immediately in the wheel listener, leading to sudden jumps.
